# A good resource for learning HTML5

Tags: html

I did google, but could not find a good ebook on HTML5. Could you suggest good resources?

Comment: better fit to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Voted to move to programmers.

Comment: Please [do not use signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts.

Answer (score 26):

**[Dive Into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/)** by **Mark Pilgrim**

Not to forget about great **[HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/)** blog containing great articles on **HTML5**.

**Note:** Not a bad idea to read about HTML 5 but we are still little away from using it. However, **[here are sites using HTML5](http://html5gallery.com/)**

Comment: I Like the HTML5 doctor site! Thnx :-)

Comment: @Rob: Yeah it's great resource on HTML5 :)

Comment: I like the html5 doctor, anything that I can read offline  - pdfs

Comment: @Jean: Not sure but you can use the HTTrack software to download the site and read offline. http://www.httrack.com/. Also someone told me that you can use google chrome to read sites offline. Thanks

Comment: Maybe also interresting to mention; Google is also fully HTML5, and they're experimenting with HTML5 in youtube at http://www.youtube.com/html5

Comment: @Rob: That is great to know :)

Comment: @Sarfraz you're welcome. I did some research a few months ago in a schoolproject and figured that out :) Though i never found the html5 doctor site at that time. We definately could have used it.

Answer (score 11):

[Dive Into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/) by Mark Pilgrim is pretty good.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly i don't expect there is an e-book. The HTML5 specification is still under development and far from ready. There are tutorials, blogs and lots of articles about it and yes browsers are busy implementing what they can (except IE is falling behind as often, but they'll catch up in IE9). But it's to early to start writing e-books about this subject.

EDIT:  take at look at [html5tutorial](http://html5tutorial.net/)

EDIT2: Site of the [Whatwg](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/). This page shows the current working draft of HTML5

Comment: +1. Any ‘book’ that claims comprehensive coverage of HTML5 is lying to you. We don't know exactly what HTML5 is yet, never mind the browser support.

Answer (score 1):

Here is good PDF book: [Sergey’s HTML5 & CSS3 Quick Reference: eBook edition](http://www.borders.com/online/store/TitleDetail?sku=0983386706)

Answer (score 0):

Well ther is offcourse the offical specifications (which is still a draft version) where you can find a lot of usefull information:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/

Also an overview of the differences with HTML 4:
http://dev.w3.org/html5/html4-differences/

Answer (score 0):

My new eBook on HTML5 discusses the core elements
[http://www.amazon.com/HTML5-Tag-Structure-ebook/dp/B003FW3IJA/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&s=digital-text&qid=1271339858&sr=8-4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003FW3IJA)

Let me know what you think.

Comment: I think there is no way to preview it, no sign of how long it is, that it is too early to publish books about HTML5, and that Amazon are refusing to sell it to me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found the new release from O'Reilly, HTML5 Cookbook by Christopher Schmitt and Kyle Simpson quite helpful, though I have to admit there are some filler pages with repeated content.

http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920016038.do